# Neo4j CompositeIndex using relationship

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a (simplified) data model like this:

```
@NodeEntity
class MyNode {
    String name;

    @Relationship(value = "REL")
    RelParent parent;
}
```

I am trying to create a composite index on uniqueness of name and parent, so a MyNode object cannot exist with same name and same parent (they can exist with same name but different parent).

I tried with:

```
@CompositeIndex(value= {"name", "parent"}, unique=true)
```

But that throws an exception:  org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MetadataException: Incorrect CompositeIndex definition on MyNode. Property parent does not exists.

Is there a way to use CompositeIndex in the way I tried above?

Comment: Are you using the Neo4j community or enterprise version?

Comment: I am using nterprise version.